# Many to many always deletes rows on both tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, cascading-deletes

When I delete a parent object (not owning one), It delete the row in the other table too, although it might be still referenced by another entities from the first table. I just want to delete the entity in the first table, and of course in the many-to-many connecting table. I have cascade type set to all on both sides, otherwise I get error, saying It is still referenced by a foreign key. I hope I was clear enough.

First table Foo:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id_foo")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "foos")
public List<Bar> getBars() {
    return bars;
}

public void setBars(List<Bar> bars) {
    this.bars= bars;
}
...
```

Second table Bar:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id_bar")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
        name = "foo_bars",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_bar") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_foo") })
public List<Foo> getFoos() {
    return foos;
}


public void setFoos(List<Foo> foos) {
    this.foos= foos;
}
...
```

I then try to remove a Foo instance.

The mapping table for the two tables doesn't have primary key, could that be a problem?

Comment: no it wasn't. We need to see your annotated POJOs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you remove Foo, you have to detach it from the corresponding bars, otherwise you get your exception. With cascade=all you are asking to remove together with Foo the referenced Bars so you had another content missing.

so, before you delete foo, you have to do it:

```
for (Bar b: foo.getBars()) b.getFoos().remove(foo);
EM.remove(foo);
```

Comment: I've tried this already and it deletes rows in both of the tables.

Comment: Have your removed the cascade = CascadeType.ALL? Don't you have triggers or ON DELETE CASCADE in the DB?

Comment: If I remove CascadeType.ALL, I cant' even persist the data.

Comment: Do you know what it actually mean? The difference between ALL, PERSIST, MERGE.... You don't want ALL cause it implies the DELETE on remove operations. In your case it doesn't make sense on any of the entities as you have twice ManyToMany, normally it would stay on the parent of OneToMany side operation. You can add cascade persist, merge. Also you can persist object without cascade, you only have to make sure that all the newly created bars elements when added to foo are also manually persisted (EM.persist(bar))

Comment: Sorry for such a late response. Your last comment made me think. I wanted to do everything with annotations and forgot that certain complex things just can't be made just with annotations. After that realization, it was straightforward problem.